# Unable to start or uninstall my Google Chrome 5 in Windows 7 X86 machine

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, uninstall

The uninstaller and the program (.exe) doesn't start at all.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more details.  What errors are you seeing?  What have you tried?

Comment: no error at all.. the uninstaller and the program (.exe) doesnt start at all !

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the lastest installer and reinstalling over the top.  It should either just work or the installer will prompt you to uninstall.